# How to set `configuredTimeOffsetFromLive` for Live HLS in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am trying to play Live HLS stream from AVPlayer. My HLS file `m3u8` has entries of 10 tracks at once and each track has a duration of 4 seconds. Now AVPlayer is making a request for the last chunk of the playlist, but I want the AVPlayer make request 2 chunks behind the live (8th chunk of playlist). I tried configuring this scenario with variable `configuredTimeOffsetFromLive`, `automaticallyPreservesTimeOffsetFromLive`, `automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling` and `preferredForwardBufferDuration`.

I have tried to set below values

```swift
        player.currentItem?.automaticallyPreservesTimeOffsetFromLive = true
        player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
        player.currentItem?.preferredForwardBufferDuration = TimeInterval.init(4)
        player.currentItem?.configuredTimeOffsetFromLive = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(12, 1000000)
```

But i could not notice anything different.
Need help to configure these values.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! It looks like we experience the same issue. Did you find a solution?